# Someone parked a domain on my server/IP - should I worry?

Tags: domain-name-system, security, ip, dedicated-server, hostname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anything I can do about someone who has pointed their domain at my ip?](https://serverfault.com/questions/146621/is-there-anything-i-can-do-about-someone-who-has-pointed-their-domain-at-my-ip)

I'm running a dedicated server with own static IP for a while now. Some weeks ago I noticed while browsing logs some domain showing up and I was wondering why. After some playing around with that domain I noticed it's a full DNS-A hostname pointing at my IP.

What's the reason someone would do that? And is there anything I should worry about or keep in mind?

Actually - I don't mind, even though I'd prefer to run the server without any hostname (IP only).

Comment: Put a "nice" vhost in place for them. :)

Comment: The folks at http://security.stackexchange.com/ may have better insight into why, but I like jscott's idea a lot.

Comment: It is actually the correct way. The question is first place why you do serve files for the wrong domain to start with ;)

Comment: There are scammers who will do this to try to get some search traffic using your content. See my question at http://serverfault.com/questions/271656/apache-scammers-point-dozens-of-domain-names-at-my-dedicated-ip-how-to-prevent

Comment: so, why is this a duplicate of "Is there anything I can do ..."? I asked what the reasons are why someone would do it and if I should worry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably a typo, but I would get in touch with the owner of the domain.

Using a whois tool you will get the Administrative and Technical contact.

You should try to have this fixed because if that domain gets associated with spamming, your IP might end up in black lists.

Most black lists have simple forms that you can fill in order to get out of them but it would be simpler to prevent that from happening...

Comment: Well, it's a domain registered by a serious online business company. I agree, this must be a typo. :)

Comment: They can't be that serious if they don't check whether they have setup the domain correctly. The least you do is a nslookup or dig to see it the domain resolves to the correct ip-address.